# C# slotmachine supposed to keep one continuous score, somehow keeps multiple separate scores

Tags: c#

I've been working on a slotmachine in C# for practise purposes, and the machine itself works as intentional. The points system, however, does not. The game starts at 100 points, and if, for example, the player lose three 5-point bets and wins 40 points on the fourth bet, the expected points would be 100-20+40=120 points. For some reason however, the code treats ALL the previous bets as being 40 point wins as well, bringing the total to 100-20+160=240 points. If the player then lose the fifth 5-point bet, the score jumps to 75.

I start by setting the 'points' value to 100, which should then update everytime the 'game()' function is called upon.

```
public static void Main()
{
    int points = 100;
    int num = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Welcome to 'Slotmachine'!\nThe aim of this game is to get a score of 1000 or higher.\nYou lose if you reach 0 or lower.\nPress enter to play");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.Clear();
    points = points + game(100);
    while(points<1000 && points>0)
    {
        num = num + 1;
        Console.WriteLine("You've played for "+num+" number of round(s)");
        points = points + game(points);
    }
}
```

The 'game()' funtion returns the players winnings, which is used to update the 'points' value (Suspect nr 1?).

Inside the game function I have a 'usrbet' which takes an input from the user (1-10), which is then fed into the 'slots()' function to determine the winnings (the 'points' that are fed from 'Main()' are checked to see what the user can bet)

```
Console.WriteLine("Here are your current points: "+points+"\nHow much would you like to bet?\nmin bet: 1\nmax bet: 10");
try
{
    usrbet = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch
{
    usrbet = 1;
}
```

```
winnings = slots(usrbet);
int RetWin = winnings - usrbet;
return RetWin;
```

Here's what the 'slots()' function does, with some examples of the winnings calculations

```
public static int slots(int usrbet)
{
    int Win;
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    Random slot = new Random();
    x = slot.Next(2,10);
    y = slot.Next(2,10);
    z = slot.Next(2,10);
    Console.WriteLine(x+""+y+""+z);
```

Example 1

```
if(x == y && y == z && x== 7)
{
    Win = usrbet*250;
    Console.WriteLine("WOW! That's incredible, you just won "+Win+"!");
}
```

Example 2

```
else if(x == z)
{
    Win = usrbet*5;
    Console.WriteLine("Congratulations, you win "+Win+".");
}
```

Example 3

```
else
{
    Win = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Ah, bummer. You didn't win anything this time.");
}
```

After that, the 'Win' value is sent back to 'game()', updating 'winnings'.

I apologize for poor formatting of the question. I'll include a link to the code, in case my problem lies elsewhere in the code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/D5TwL0

I've tried making arrays of the 'bet' and 'usrbet' variables, in an attempt to have a "new" value to update the 'points' with at every run of 'game()', but that changed absolutely nothing other than limiting how many times 'game()' can run before getting an overflow error.

Comment: This would be an excellent time to familiarize yourself with the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the problem wasn't with the code, but with the compiler. Dotnetfiddle is where I made the code and had the issue, but trying it in another compiler, it managed to count just fine.